# what is the appropraite version of zookeeper?

Tags: java, maven, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm

i'm new to `storm` ,`zookeeper` and `java` 
Now i imported project using `storm -0.8.2` with recommended `maven -3.X` 
but i don't know what is the `version of zookeeper` and `version of maven`  that i should install it !!?

and i installed `java 7`

```
java -version 
java version "1.7.0_80"
```

is there problem with using another version of java  that coder used another ? 
or is there any problem of using java 7 with old version of storm ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problems to use Java 7 with storm 0.8.2 as I done it. But stay away from zookeeper 3.3.3. Try zookeeper 3.3.5 or higher since the 3.3.3 caused storm workers to hang, crash or stop after 4-5 hours.

As for maven, Maven 3.3 will work fine to build jar compatible with storm.

Comment: thanks , but is there any problem if coder used zookeeper-3.3.3 with storm -0.8.2 ? i mean should i use same version he used or no ?

Comment: You can use the zookeeper-3.3.3.jar installed in storm and deploy zookeeper 3.3.5 on each node. It will work.

Comment: last question in this point , how can i check version of zookeeper he used ? i mean where can i find zookeeper -version ?

Comment: Check this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/314210/how-do-i-find-out-the-version-of-zookeeper-i-am-running

Comment: i got the link but i'm asking about the version of zookeeper of the code i imported it ? how can i check it ?

Comment: If it's in the Java code, the version is in the name of the jar file. You must pay special attention to the zookeeper that storm will use in the cluster.

Comment: thanks , so i should install maven first to package the code then i'll know version of zookeeper after that from the name of the jar right ?